# Enabling Spring method validation in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-validator

I've followed the instructions in the Spring 4.0.5 documentation for configuring Bean Validation in the container, with Hibernate Validator 5.1 and this (Groovy) configuration class:

```
@Configuration("validationConfig")
@Import(CreatorConfig)
@ImportResource("/META-INF/spring/mockito-mocks.xml")
static class Config {
    @Bean
    validator() {
        new LocalValidatorFactoryBean()
    }

    @Bean
    mvpp() {
        new MethodValidationPostProcessor()
    }
}
```

My class being tested is instantiated in the referenced `CreatorConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("validationConfig")
static class CreatorConfig {
    @Bean
    ticketCreator(TicketRepository tickets) {
        new UploadTicketCreator(tickets)
    }
}
```

I separated this out into a separate configuration class under the belief that I needed the postprocessor registered before creating the `UploadTicketCreator` bean, which is annotated according to the documentation:

```
@Validated
public class UploadTicketCreator {
    public UploadTicket createTicket(@Valid CreateTicketRequest request) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm then injecting the `UploadTicketCreator` into the test case. I've verified that the autowiring is operating properly (the field is populated, and its own `tickets` field is a Mockito mock). However, the validation logic is not being applied to my creator bean, and the injected bean is the raw POJO without any proxying.

Am I missing a piece of the validation setup? Is there an additional required step not mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Does the log contain any information on what's going on with `MethodValidationPostProcessor`?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring configuration processor appears to be inspecting the declared return type of the bean declarations. I was using Groovy's implicit return type, which presumably was compiled to `Object`, and adding an explicit return type of `MethodValidationPostProcessor` or even `BeanPostProcessor` caused the validation advice to be applied.